# How do I access and use resources ID's that have been created programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I'm new-ish to Android and am trying to make a Hangman game but I'm having a problem (*as in, I can't work out how to*) accessing TextViews that have been programmatically created.

I have searched around on SO and elsewhere and there is plenty on setting ID's using either pre or post API 17 methods of `textView.setId(View.generateViewId());` or creating a bank of ID resources and assigning them, but that doesn't help me as far as I can see as I don't know how many views will be created per turn (*a word is picked at random and TextViews are created per letter*).

Currently I am creating the views as follows:

```
private void createViewsForLetters(List<String> letters) {
    for (String letter : letters) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textView.setText(letter);
        textView.setTextSize(50);
        textView.setLetterSpacing(0.5f);
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Will become visible on successful entry
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        Log.v("HMmsg: TV ID's", String.valueOf(textView.getId()));
    }
}
```

Which log out id's of `TV ID's: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

- So, how do I access these and what about when the number of TextViews
  change depending on the size of the random word selected?

I ideally would like to be able to get the user's character entry and check if it is in the array of letters that the random word has been split in to (*which I've done below*) but then **get the ID of the TextView that that index number represents** so that I can use it to make the corresponding letter visible again... HANGMAN!

I am using this (which works as it is) to validate user entries:

```
private void actionUserEntry(List<String> letters) {
        if (currentLetter.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must enter something!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (letters.toString().contains(currentLetter)) {
                Log.v("HMmsg", currentLetter + " is in the word");
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                //TODO capture generated viewId to setVisibility on correct entry

            } else {
                Log.v("HMmsg", currentLetter + " is NOT in the word");
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I just need a bit of help with the TODO in the above code, if you please!

Thanks =)

Comment: Why do you need to access them by id?  Can't you keep references to them, or access them by tag?

Comment: @nasch Thanks very much for that, with a bit fiddling I did it with tags... and learnt a bit on the way too! Cheers.